# Sass hierarchy and multiple elements

Tags: angular, sass

I'm using angular and I want to update material radio buttons and checks only for those that are inside a class, I need to include in styles.scss because of this _ngcontent  that angular includes, so I have:

```
.class1 
  mat-radio-button,
  mat-select,
  mat-checkbox {
   color: red;
   line-height: 36px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

From my understanding, this should apply to those mat-radio-button, mat-select and mat-checkbox that are included in parent that have class1.

But somehow,it applies also to other items without "class1 parent", what I think is I'm not doing it well the css selector, I want:

```
all mat-radio-button, mat-select or mat-checkbox with a parent with class class1
```

How can I create this css selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SCSS is wrong:

```
.class1 {
  mat-radio-button,
  mat-select,
  mat-checkbox {
   color: red;
   line-height: 36px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
}
```

The way you have it it only works for `.class1 mat-radio-button`, but not for `mat-select` or `mat-checkbox` .

Check out the [Nesting part on the SCSS guide.](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3)

Comment: so, should it be .class1 mat-radio-button, .class1 mat-select, .class1 mat-checkbox {} ???

Comment: In the compiled CSS, yes. If you struggle with this I would really adivse you to have a better look at how CSS works.